# How to get line by line coverage xml file in Emma- maven project

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, code-coverage, emma

I am using the Emma tool in Maven project. Emma creates line by line code coverage in HTML file, it does not display line by line code coverage XML  file. It gives only a summary XML file. Is there a way to keep or generate line by line code coverage XML file in Emma?

I have entered following plugin in my `pom.xml`

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <configuration>
        <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Am I missing any configuration? If so where should I enter it in pom? (A complete `pom.xml` file will be appreciated).

I have created my project using Eclipse and ran it in cmd using the code:

```
mvn emma:emma
```

also i have entered following inside the Emma-maven pluggin

```
<configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the property [`maven.emma.report.xml`](http://emma.sourceforge.net/maven-emma-plugin/properties.html) to `true` to generate a XML report (it is `false` by default). The file `target/coverage.xml` will be generated.

Sample command:

```
mvn emma:emma -Dmaven.emma.report.xml=true
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response Tunaki. But  still it displays code coverage summary xml file. (Not the  line by line code coverage XML file.) I  modified my pom.xml file as I have edited in my post. Still didn't get the  line by line code coverage XML file.