# coverage.ec File Format

Tags: java, code-coverage, file-format, emma

When using Emma to produce code coverage reports, it generates coverage.ec file, which is to be given to emma.jar again to produce a report. However I need a custom report and I do not want to use Emma report as a proxy, i.e ***I want to read the coverage.ec file directly.*** But I do not know the format of this file and my search has not been successful so far. So here's the question:

What is the format of coverage.ec file generated by Emma.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `coverage.ec` uses an internal Emma specific file format. It feels wrong that you directly want to use it. Instead you should generate e.g. the XML report, which should contain all the required data you need in a readable and easy to parse format.

check https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724337/1515052 to generate the XML report.

Comment: Thank you. I already generate the XML report. What I want to do is to find out the identity of the covered statements. I do not care what those statements actually are or where they are. I just need to know the id of covered statements. I am able to achieve what I want with an XML, but it feels wrong because it generates a lot of data I won't use so there should be a more efficient way.

Comment: the code is open source. You can still try to find it out: https://github.com/ehelms/Emma
But if you already have a working solution with XML, I would not spent the time on it.